# Not able to use an if statement in python shell

Tags: python, python-idle

i am new to python and i want to write a simple function which will get some input and print it accordingly, something like this

```
def printer(data):
if data<5:
print('data is less than 5')
else:
print('data is greater than 5')
return;
```

but when i run this code, i get an

> 'unexpected indent'

error, what am i doing wrong

[image]

Comment: Align your code properly. In Python indentation matters.

Comment: You should have a look at a [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

As the error points out, you need to indent your code as required by Python language. So after typing `if condition1:`, hit enter, then hit tab and write your following code.

```
def printer(data):
    if data<5:
       print('data is less than 5')
    else:
       print('data is greater than 5')
    return
```

And don't put a `;` at the end of your function, this is not JS.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Python! You need to make sure your code is [properly indented](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3). Python doesn't use braces to mark sections, instead, it uses indentation. Just like missing a brace in another language, you need to make sure the indentation is right.

```
def printer(data):
    if data<5:
        print('data is less than 5')
    else:
        print('data is greater than 5')
```

No need for a return if there is no return value, and Python doesn't use semi-colons as end of statement markers.

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected indent in the picture is the initial space before `def`, as indicated by the red rectangle.  (This is an IDLE feature, so I suspect you are using IDLE.)

When you fix that, see AIG's or Rostan's answer.